# Collect all downtime start times to reach total downtime at end of month - PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I have a cron job running every 10-15 minutes pinging minecraft servers in my database, and if one of them returns "offline", the database records the time this happened and sticks in it the `lastDT` (last downtime) table. My question is, how can I collect all of the times, and at the end of each month figure out the average downtime (if any). I assume this would be `((totalMinutesInMonth-totalMinutesOfDT)*100)`. Is there a way to do this? To get a better idea of what I'm dealing with, here is some code to reference:

```
<?php
  require_once './inc/connectToDB.php';
  date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  session_start();

  try {
  $collectServers = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM servers');
  $collectServers->execute();
  $serversDat = $collectServers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit();
  }

  foreach ($serversDat as $server) {
    try {
      $remoteCon = @fsockopen(@gethostbyname($server['address']),$server['port'],$errno,$errstr,1);
      $connected = false;
      if (@is_resource($remoteCon)) { $connected = true; @fclose($remoteCon); }
      if ($connected) { $serverStat = 'Online'; } else { $serverStat = 'Offline'; }
      if ($serverStat == 'Offline') {
    $downTime=date('H:i:s',time());
      } else {
    $downTime=0;
      }
      $reinsert = $database->prepare('UPDATE servers SET status=:status,lastPing=:time,lastDT=:lastdt WHERE id=:id');
      $reinsert->bindValue(':id',$server['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $reinsert->bindValue(':status',$serverStat,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $reinsert->bindValue(':time',date('H:sa T',time()),PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $reinsert->bindValue(':lastdt',$downTime,PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $reinsert->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      error_log($e->getMessage());
      exit();
    }
  }

  unset($database);
  exit();
?>
```

The database table looks like:

[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht0Ha.png)

If I can provide more info, I'd be glad to do so. Not sure what to do from here, however. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If anyone has any idea how to do this more efficiently, I'm all for rewriting. This is not working out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like finding the time the server went down is only half of the equation. You will also need to know when the server came back up.

```
Down at 10:00AM, Up at 10:15AM equals 15min downtime.
```

You will need to store that in the database somewhere. That isn't solution, but it does seem like the next step.

Comment: Ah, true. I'll see what I can do with this. I'll leave the question open for now, though. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you have an idea how to possibly do this more efficiently, I'm all for rewriting.

Comment: If you wanted to be pessimistic you could assume that every offline response resulted in 15 minutes of downtime.

Comment: ^I realize you were probably being sarcastic but that gave me a great idea<3 thanks